# How to transfer en bloc all the cells of a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

So I found this [great visualization of Newton's unconstrained optimization](https://github.com/RInterested/notebooks/blob/master/visualizing-and-animating-optimization-algorithms-with-matplotlib.ipynb) on a Jupyter Notebook within Louis Tiao's public account, and I want to run it on my laptop.

With other platforms, I'd be able to just copy and paste (including the annotations), and get it ready to "play". But with Notebook, I have to deal with multiple cells, and copy and paste each one separately, and in order.

Is there a more expeditious way of transferring the code?

Comment: Why not click the download button?

Comment: @brian [This is what pops up](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RInterested/notebooks/master/visualizing-and-animating-optimization-algorithms-with-matplotlib.ipynb).

Comment: Yes jupyter notebooks look like json files if you look at the raw content. You should still be able to download that file and open it through the jupyter notebook tree

Comment: Unfortunately, an answer has been deleted. So, provided my OP is not downvoted, I'll leave here a short-cut that does work, and that I found thanks to the erased answer: Right-click on the `Download` button on the GitHub page, and select `Saved linked content as...` Now just name the `.ipynb` file, and save it.

Answer (score 0):

A jupyter notebook is stored in a file with a .ipynb extension.  The internals of the file a specially formatted text called json (or similar to it).

Right click the link and save as name.ipynb (it defaults to this in windows on chrome) and choose a location to save it.  The best location is one where you have all your notebooks by default.

Then run jupyter and open the file.

Comment: When you say the link, you don't mind the URL (which does end in .ipynb), do you? The pop-up menu doesn't include a saving option. If you click on the Download button within GibHub, as you suggested, there is no download either, but rather what I linked in my comment to the OP...

Comment: I just found out that right-clicking on the Download button on the GitHub interface, does give you the option to save the file... Is this what you meant?